# Unrar file from archive that starts with a dash

Tags: unrar

How do you extract a single file from a rar archive that starts with a dash?
e.g. the archive listing looks like:

-= foo =-.jpg
   -= bar =-.jpg

I've tried 
`unrar e archive.rar ./-= foo =-.jpg`
and
`unrar e archive.rar "./-= foo =-.jpg"`
but unrar seems to read that as the literal filename.
I've also tried `unrar e archive.rar \-=\ foo\ =-.jpg` without success.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get unrar to process the file correctly, I found about a handy operator , the double dash --, that seems to work system-wide by telling the system to end all option processing.

`unrar e archive.rar -- "-= foo =-.jpg"` does the trick